# How to programmatically determine all valid XML nodes from a schema

Tags: java, xsd

Is there an existing Java library that will let me determine all valid nodes for a point in an XML document (specified by XPath, or otherwise), given an XML schema?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664422/convert-xsd-to-tree-structure-with-java)?

Comment: @home : The question at that link appears to have no answer, and is more concerned with parsing the schema than checking for valid elements at a specific point in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a very helpful answer - hopefully something better will come along.

I don't think what you want is out there in an easily usable form.  Obviously, the functionality is embedded in various editors, but not necessarily in a form that's easily and/or legally reusable.

If you were to try to roll your own, you'd probably want to start with a pre-built XSD object model if possible.  There are three that I'm aware of.  I've used none - just thought I was going to but ended up not.

[XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/) is the one best wrapped for reuse.  FWIW, it's by the enviably prolific Kohsuke Kawaguchi, creator of Hudson/Jenkins and a bunch of other stuff.

There's also one embedded in Xerces, and one in the Eclipse XML support.  In both cases, my ill-informed opinion is that documentation is sketchy and reuse, while theoretically possible, is not something the authors have paid much attention to supporting.

Comment: Looks like you're right, as far as I can tell. I ended up using XSOM, and doing it semi-manually.

Answer (score 0):

check javax.xml.validation and the XPath libraries at javax.xml.xpath

Comment: These don't have anything that would help with what he is asking, do they?  Am I missing something?