# How XSD can be converted into Parent child structure in a Java String?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd2code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="dsddsf" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="rootElement">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="names" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="name" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="places" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="place" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element name="origin" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="current" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

From the above structure I need to get a list of string like below:     
rootElement

rootElement.names

rootElement.places

rootElement.places.place

Comment: A plus one for such great formatting being a new user! and obviously for an interesting question.

Comment: i didn't understood your reply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert XSD to tree structure with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664422/convert-xsd-to-tree-structure-with-java)

Comment: Maybe you can use [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/). [Example](http://www.slideshare.net/rajighawi/java-and-xml-schema)